# Multi Org Marketing Cloud Connect Woes

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, multi-org

I am implementing a multi org setup for SFMC and hit a blocker.

1. I have not been able to use profile attributes for personalization. This means that all profile data has to be brought in from SFDC, which leads to my second woe.
2. The 15 minutes lag for Data Stream falls short of the clients requirements.

Interested in hearing from folks that have encountered this problem, and possible work arounds. Is it possible to have a real time update from SFDC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For personalization, you can map attributes to fields in SFDC-Objects (for further info check out the Marketing Cloud documentation on [Attribute Properties](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/profile_and_preference_attributes/attribute_properties/). I'm afraid there is no possibility to use realtime sync for these attributes.

However for use in journey builder, you can use salesforce data events (further info can be found in the Marketing Cloud documentation about [The Salesforce Data Event](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/entry_events/using_the_salesforce_sales_and_service_cloud_event/)) to get realtime updates/journey injections from SFDC. Then you can inject the needed data into the journey and read it from event data rather than contact data.

When using triggered sends, you can also provide the details read from SFDC as attribute to the send definition and use this information rather then the subscriber data.

I hope this helps for your use cases.